# remove named ranges in google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

I've searched for a way to remove named ranges in google apps scripts (script bound to Sheets), but I can't find a way to list them or to delete them.

I'm trying to avoid conflicts with named ranges I create as part of my add-on setup.

Or should I just tolerate a 'dirty' list and rely on resetting the named ranges with my setup function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// The code below creates a new named range "foo", and then remove it.
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
ss.setNamedRange("foo", ss.getActiveRange());
ss.removeNamedRange("foo");
```

[Docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#removeNamedRange(String))

can't change them - [issue 1721](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1721)

Comment: Thanks. Don't know why I couldn't find that. I must have walked by it several times.

Answer (score 0):

#### To list named ranges:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getnamedranges

```
const namedRanges: GoogleAppsScript.Spreadsheet.NamedRange[] = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getNamedRanges();
Logger.log("List of named ranges in SpreadSheet:");
for (const namedRange of namedRanges) {
    Logger.log(namedRange.getName());
}
```

#### To delete/remove the named ranges:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/named-range#remove

```
const namedRanges: GoogleAppsScript.Spreadsheet.NamedRange[] = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getNamedRanges();
for (const namedRange of namedRanges) {
    Logger.log(`Removing named range: ${namedRange.getName()}`);
    namedRange.remove();

    // OR
    // SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().removeNamedRange(namedRange.getName());
}
```

---

#### Note

"Removing" a named range does not remove the contents of the range. It just removes the name associated with the range.

#### To remove the contents as well:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#clear

```
const namedRanges: GoogleAppsScript.Spreadsheet.NamedRange[] = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getNamedRanges();
for (const namedRange of namedRanges) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().removeNamedRange(namedRange.getName());
    const range = namedRange.getRange();
    // clear the range content
    range.clear();
}
```